# Midnight transport fron Keflavik international airport to Reykjavik

Tags: airports, iceland, reykjavik

I am planning a trip for the Christmass holidays to Reykjavik. I will arrive at Keflavik international airport a little bit past midnight, and I am having trouble finding a way to get to Reykjavik city centre, where I will be staying.

I have looked into Straeto/Klappi but I see that the first bus I could take would be around 7AM.

Is calling a taxi my only option? How much should I expect to be charged?

Also, this is my first post in TravelStackExchange, feel free to let me know of ways to improve this question.

Comment: [Wikivoyage](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Keflav%C3%ADk_International_Airport) claims that a taxi from Keflavik Airport to Reykjavik for 1–4 passengers costs about 14000 ISK (≈ 100 USD ≈ 95 EUR ≈ 80 GBP).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common option is to use the Flybus but there is also a competing company: [Grayline](https://grayline.is/airport-transfer/airport-express-schedule). See if their schedule could suit you. Either way you are looking to spend €20+ per trip/person.

Keep in mind that a regular Flybus ticket takes you to the BSÍ terminal, which is at a certain distance from the city center. Since you will be arriving late and presumably are not familiar with the town you might want to consider the Flybus plus option: upon arrival at the BSÍ terminal passengers are dispatched to minibuses and driven to their hotels. I would suggest this option for a first-time visitor. Even if you don't mind walking and dragging your bags at night the weather may be slightly uninviting.

For the return trip, the choice is yours. You can meet up at the BSÍ terminal or choose the Flybus plus option again, and they will pick you up at your hotel if you want.

The trip from the airport to downtown Reykjavík takes about 45 minutes. Using a taxi is going to be expensive, like everything else in Iceland. It could make sense for a group of persons to pool expenses, but won't be much faster.

For the return trip consider Strætó line 55 (also departing from BSI terminal) if you will be leaving during the day. It's cheaper but the trip is a bit longer.

PS: if you plan to rent a car it makes sense to rent it in Keflavík and you bring it back there when you leave Iceland.

Also note that the vast majority of restaurants are closed at Xmas. Either stock up some food or be sure to book a table in advance and of course it won't be cheap. Welcome to Iceland!

Comment: Thank you for a very detailed answer! Grayline sounds the most promising option as they cover every possible hour of the day, or at least that's what their site says. 

I'm probably going to try that or taking a taxi, which might be a little bit cheaper than the premium drop-off-at-home Grayline option. 

Do you have any idea on whether there are taxis waiting in arrivals or should I expect to call one in advance? I know this might be an issue in some of the smaller airports I have visited.

Comment: @gummy_joe I have no ideas about the taxis, I've never paid attention.
One thing I forgot to mention though: the Flybus does not depart immediately, the driver waits for the bus to fill up. It can easily take 20 minutes before you get going. Also it's possible to buy the ticket on the spot if you have not booked in advance. In my experience there are always seats available.

Answer (score 6):

You can try https://www.re.is/tour/flybus/ . They claim to serve all arrivals.

Personally I would probably stay the night in an Keflavik airport hotel and head into Reykjavik the next day. At the moment airport hotels are very reasonably priced (given that Iceland is a expensive destination in the first place).